# Magento Shopping cart sales rule not removed when applicable product removed from cart

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have added two products one is for eligible coupons another one not eligible.

Then  I applied coupon code, code is applied fine. 
After some time I removed coupon eligible item, coupon code is not showing, but when I added again same item to cart it automatically came.
How to remove coupon code when applicable product removed from cart.

steps to reproduce issue.

```
1>add two prodcts one applicable and another one is not applicable item
2> apply coupon code
3> getquote[estimate]
4> remove applicable item
5>after remove done add again
5>getquote[estimate]
```